# How to Get the Facebook like and Share count wordpress website?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having problem while trying to get the Facebook like count for my website.
I used the following coding -

```
 api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22url%22
```

Also

```
  api.facebook.com/restserve.php?method=links.getStats&urls=
```

url I tried to add to show the data like 'Share Count', etc, but I am ending up at an error.

If you could please try on your site and change the URL (i.e. http://www.techgeck.com) as per your need and see if its working on your website and where m doing problem??

Your help would be really beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

The Rest API endpoints will be deprecated on April 30th, 2015. If you have a v2.0 app, you can use

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/fql={fql_query}&access_token={access_token}
```

as endpoint (until August 7th, 2016). If otherwise, you can only use

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/?id={url}
```

to be able to get the share counts.